# How to calculate rank based on total marks

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables i want to display the 3 table data in single table based on primary key, foreign key the result came perfectly! But i need to calculate rank based on the total marks from my second table.

result screenshot:
[image]

Please anyone tell me the query to calculate rank

I used the following mysql query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT s.student_name
     , s.contact_number
     , m.total
     , m.rank
     , p.father_name 
  FROM student_details s 
  JOIN mark m
    ON s.student_id = m.student_id 
  JOIN parents_details p
    ON p.student_id = s.student_id 
 WHERE s.student_name = '".$_POST['student_name']."' 
");

echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='15' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>CONTACT NUMBER</th>
<th>TOTAL MARK</th>
<th>RANK</th>
<th>FATHER NAME</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contact_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rank'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['father_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

}?>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your code is illegible, and your sample one row output does little to make your question understandable.

Comment: Not getting your desired output did you want rank based on ascending or descending order

Comment: Also, see about prepared and bound statements

Comment: yes exactly! i need to calculate rank based on my total marks from my table and display the rank in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT @rank := @rank+1 finalrank,ZZ.* FROM
    (
        SELECT student_details.student_name, 
        student_details.contact_number, mark.total, 
        mark.rank, parents_details.father_name 
        FROM student_details 
        INNER JOIN mark ON student_details.student_id=mark.student_id 
        INNER JOIN parents_details ON parents_details.student_id=student_details.student_id ,(SELECT @rank:=0)z
        ORDER BY mark.total desc
    )ZZ
)ZZZ 
WHERE ZZZ.student_name = '".$_POST['student_name']."'
```

Just try above query.

Here I had used `SELECT @rank:=0` and `@rank := @rank+1`.

Comment: its working! But it shows rank 7 but i have 4 data in my table ! how to solve this?

Comment: just provide your sample data.

Comment: i added my sample data screen shot above, and executed sql query screenshot also

Comment: it works but when i add new data it gives wrong information! please find the  my updated screenshot

Comment: @M.Lak You just try to execute with my updated query,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151863/discussion-between-m-lak-and-sagar-gangwal).